# MySQL Select, where field is not in a CSV list in another field

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a table like this

```
fieldA  | fieldB
-----------------
a       | a,b,c
-----------------
b       | a,c
-----------------
c       | x,y,z
```

where fieldA is a string and fieldB is a CSV list.

I need to build a query that would do something similar to what I was hoping to get from this query:

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE fieldA NOT IN fieldB

(would select if fieldA is not on the CSV list in fieldB)

or an inferior but usable query might me something like this:

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE fieldA NOT LIKE %fieldB%

(would select if fieldA is not a substring of fieldB)

Result would be something like this:

```
fieldA  | fieldB
-----------------
b       | a,c
-----------------
c       | x,y,z
```

Comment: @hbgoddard "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'fieldB" and "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%fieldB%", respectively. I know this should work if I had a specific array or a string (respectively) but for some reason this doesn't work when comparing a field to another field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE  NOT FIND_IN_SET(fieldA,fieldB)
```

Your are looking for [FIND_IN_SET](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_find_in_set.asp) in mysql.

**NOTE: FIND_IN_SET is known to perform poorly. Do think twice before using in production environment**

Comment: Great, works perfectly :)
I ended up doing this in PHP instead when I wasn't finding the answer. Given your warning about performance, I'll stick to the PHP. But this is definitely what I was asking for.